# Is Docker or Vagrant a solution to safely "package" a web app?

Tags: web-applications, docker, vagrant

I'm working as an intern on a web application, in a company that does not do web development nor sysadmin. **This app lives on the backup server** (a Mac Mini used as a Time Machine drive) where I installed the MEAN stack and several other tools that were needed.

As the company is not very tech-savvy and will probably mess with the software one day or another, **I was wondering if I could "package" the app inside a Docker or Vagrant container** to relaunch it in a single command, with all the tools and configuration set up, and to also make it portable in the case where the app should be installed on another machine.

---

**TL;DR** Can I package a web app and its stack in a Docker/Vagrant container to make it easy to install & run?

Comment: you should read https://docs.docker.com/examples/nodejs_web_app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I package a web app and its stack in a Docker/Vagrant container to make it easy to install & run?

Yes, with both of them.

## With Vagrant

First, Vagrant isn't my favorite solution, but here's what you can do: You can write a Vagrantfile which pulls the Linux image you want, installs your stuff (e.g. a Tomcat or NGINX server), configures everything (folder structure, open ports) and copies your final application to the image (e.g. a WAR file). Now you got everything you need inside a VM image and you can just share this image to make you company able to run your application.

#### Pros

- Everything is on one image
- If the image runs and your company got problems, they can easily connect to the VM (via SSH) and maybe fix it.

#### Cons

- The image might be very big (many GBs)
- If you use Vagrant, you would typically share the Vagrantfile to others, not the VM image it builds (but that's not what you want)

## With Docker

With Docker you would package you application and its dependencies into images. Note that you would package every dependency (e.g. your database) into a separate image, not all in one image. The images would be build by Dockerfiles and you can upload them to a Docker Registry or export them as files to your disk. You can share them (either by sharing the file or preferable by pulling them from a Docker Registry) and write a script to run them all together to start your application.

#### Pros

- Smaller images compared to VM images (see above)
- Docker is made for this purpose (share ready-to-run images to others)

#### Cons

- If you got a problem when the app runs, it might be more difficult to fix that as you would need to build a new image

## IMHO

Package everything into Docker images. Write a script to run all images together (you can just write some shell scrip, but you can also use some fancy Puppet, Ansible, Chef installation). That's it. Your stack is portable and easy to start.

#### Just a side note

If your company is really really very little aware of tech stuff, be careful. Every new tool (even if it is as useful as Docker is) is something new for them to learn and to maintain.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. When I tried Docker on OSX, it launched `boot2docker` in a VM and I told myself it would be a little heavy to run a VM on a VM, so why not just run & install the app on a plain ol' VM? I ended up doing this: a headless Debian 8 on VirtualBox, that launches everything on boot if something goes wrong. In just a click, the VM is launched and the app ready. It does not need to be portable, just packaged and easy to run.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) You can set it up so that everything runs in 1 command

`docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

In short, for Vagrant at least, the answer is *no*. For Docker, maybe, but...

What you really seem to be looking for, though, is a provisioning tool - which neither Docker nor Vagrant are. Your needs sound more along the lines of [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/), Chef, Salt, Puppet, etc. These are complementary to Docker and Vagrant - one of them plus a Docker container as the final result seems like the textbook example for your scenario.